# How to make files visible in FTP server

Tags: java, ftp

I am a beginner to FTP and I am facing problem while doing File Transfer. As File Transfer to FTP server is happening and once file is transferred automatically File is deleting from FTP server.

```
                String newfilename;
                FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                FileInputStream fis = null; 
                /*
                    written few set of statement for fetching file name and storing filename in **newfilename** variable and storing the file in **fis(FileInputStream).**
                */
                System.out.println("posting file "+newfilename);
                /* 
                    **ftpClient** is entered in working directory, I mean FTP server directory.
                */
                if(newfilename.startsWith("CAP1"))
                {
                    ftpClient.storeFile(newfilename, fis); 
                    record1[0].setAddr1(newfilename); //storing filename in respective column of DB
                }
                else if(newfilename.startsWith("CAP2"))
                {
                    ftpClient.storeFile(newfilename, fis);
                    record1[0].setAddr2(newfilename); //storing filename in respective column of DB
                }
                else if(newfilename.startsWith("CAP3"))
                {
                    ftpClient.storeFile(newfilename, fis);
                    record1[0].setAddr3(newfilename); //storing filename in respective column of DB
                }
```

So anyone suggest, what change I need to do with this??

Comment: i'm not sure to have understood the question but, have you tried your FTP server with an ftp client like filezilla to make sûre it works as expected ?

Comment: Do you mean that you can see the file in the server, while upload is in progress, but once it finishes, the file disappears? If my understanding is correct, how do you exactly check that?

Comment: Yes Martin its absolutely right. I am checking as per logs and data which I storing in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution for this. As Majorly FTP server is in Remote Location and once we upload image to FTP server, within a fraction of seconds those images are moving to other location because of some FTP server settings. Due to this reason I am unable to see any images from FTP server.